# necesito meter palabra por palabra de un .txt en un array

Tags: java, arraylist, guardar

necesito que de un txt de este estilo

```
1   Antonio Perez Ruiz  Programador 1200.0  Desarrollo
2   Maria   Gutierrez Jimenez   Programador 1500.0  Desarrollo
3   Juan    Tortosa Martín  Programador 2100.0  Desarrollo
4   Pedro   Perez Romera    Administrador   1000.0  Sistemas
5   Diego   Soto Ruiz   Administrador   1300.0  Sistemas
6   Helena  Lopez Perez Administrador   1400.0  Sistemas
```

meter dato por dato en un array para luego buscar cual tienen "Desarrollo" y agruparlos...

lo hice así

```
public void listado(){
     File fichero= new File ("empleado.txt");
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader (fichero);
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader (fr);

                String linea = bf.readLine ();
                while (linea!=null){
                   // System.out.println(linea);
                    AL.add(linea);
                   linea = bf.readLine ();

                }

                fr.close();            
            }



            catch (IOException ex){
                System.out.println ("Hay un error");
            }  
       System.out.println(AL);     
    }
```

el problema es que me mete lina a linea y necesito meter palabra por palabra...

al final necesito que se queden agrupados así

```
Desarrolladores:
1   Antonio Perez Ruiz  Programador 1200.0  
2   Maria   Gutierrez Jimenez   Programador 1500.0  
3   Juan    Tortosa Martín  Programador 2100.0  

Sistemas:
4   Pedro   Perez Romera    Administrador   1000.0  
5   Diego   Soto Ruiz   Administrador   1300.0  
6   Helena  Lopez Perez Administrador   1400.0
```

por lo que mi idea es meter dato a dato en un array list, buscar de 6 en 6 datos si tiene la palabra clave y luego imprimir esos datos... no se me ocurre otra cosa...

Comment: Esa duda creo que la contestan en este post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16774264/3495626

Comment: he cambiado alguna cosilla pero funciona perfectamente, gracias

Comment: Si funciona perfectamente, recuerda votar positivamente si lo crees oportuno y aceptar la respuesta pulsando en el check verde debajo de la puntuacion de la respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente deberías crearte una clase **PERSONA** o una clase donde guardes cada uno de los atributos del archivo

```
public class Persona {
    private String id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String ocupacion;
    private String sueldo;
    private String area;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getOcupacion() {
        return ocupacion;
    }

    public void setOcupacion(String ocupacion) {
        this.ocupacion = ocupacion;
    }

    public String getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }

    public void setSueldo(String sueldo) {
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }
}
```

A continuación la clase para organizar y clasificar la información:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static final String FILENAME = "/UBICACION/filename.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String sCurrentLine;

            List<String> listaString = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // EXTRAE CADA UNA DE LAS FILAS Y AÑADE A UNA LISTA
                // ADEMAS COMO EN LA CADENA EXISTEN DOS O MAS ESPACIOS                           
                // ESTOS LOS CONSOLIDA EN UNO SOLO
                listaString.add(sCurrentLine.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
            }

            // IMPRIME TODOS LOS ELEMENTOS DEL ARCHIVO
            for (String palabra : listaString) {
                System.out.println(palabra);
            }

            // SE CREA DOS LISTAS DE PERSONAS
            List<Persona> listaPersonaDesarrollo = new ArrayList<Persona>();
            List<Persona> listaPersonaSistema = new ArrayList<Persona>();

            // SEPARA LAS PALABRAS Y LAS ASIGNA SI SON DE DESARROLLO O SISTEMAS
            for (String texto : listaString) {
                String personaArray[] = texto.split(" ");
                Persona persona = new Persona();
                persona.setId(personaArray[0]);
                persona.setNombre(personaArray[1]);
                persona.setApellido(personaArray[2] + personaArray[3]);
                persona.setOcupacion(personaArray[4]);
                persona.setSueldo(personaArray[5]);
                persona.setArea(personaArray[6]);
                if (personaArray[6].equals("Desarrollo"))
                    listaPersonaDesarrollo.add(persona);
                else if (personaArray[6].equals("Sistemas"))
                    listaPersonaSistema.add(persona);
            }

            // IMPRIME LAS PERSONAS CLASIFICADAS

            System.out.println("Personas en desarrollo:");
            System.out
                    .println("........................................................");
            for (Persona persona : listaPersonaDesarrollo) {
                System.out.println(persona.getId() + " " + persona.getNombre()
                        + " " + persona.getApellido() + " "
                        + persona.getOcupacion() + " " + persona.getSueldo()
                        + " " + persona.getArea());
            }

            System.out.println("Personas en sistemas:");
            System.out
                    .println("........................................................");
            for (Persona persona : listaPersonaSistema) {
                System.out.println(persona.getId() + " " + persona.getNombre()
                        + " " + persona.getApellido() + " "
                        + persona.getOcupacion() + " " + persona.getSueldo()
                        + " " + persona.getArea());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

En la consola el resultado da lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]